# .Net Core WPF MVVM menu using ItemContainerTemplate not working

Tags: wpf, .net-core, menu, contextmenu

I have used a MVVM menu approach in my WPF applications in .NET Framework. After converting to .NET Core 3.1 that same approach is no longer working.

Question: Is this a bug in WPF? Does anyone know of a solution or workaround?

**The end result in .NET Framework 4.7.2.**

[image]

**The same code in .NET Core 3.1 will show MenuItem inside MenuItem(?). Submenus do not appear.**

[image]

Here is a simplified version of the view models.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfMenuFw
{
    class MainVm
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuVm> MenuVms { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuVm>();
    }

    abstract class MenuVm
    {
    }

    class MenuSeparatorVm : MenuVm
    {
    }

    class MenuItemVm : MenuVm
    {
        public string Header { get; set; } = nameof(MenuItemVm);
    }

    class MenuGroupVm : MenuVm
    {
        public string Header { get; set; } = nameof(MenuGroupVm);
        public ObservableCollection<MenuVm> MenuVms { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuVm>();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfMenuFw.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMenuFw"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainVm}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuSeparatorVm}">
            <Separator />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>

        <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuGroupVm}">
            <MenuItem
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MenuGroupVm}"
                Header="{Binding Header}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuVms}"
                UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>

        <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemVm}">
            <MenuItem 
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MenuItemVm}" 
                Header="{Binding Header}" />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainVm>
            <local:MainVm.MenuVms>
                <local:MenuGroupVm Header="Group 1">
                    <local:MenuGroupVm.MenuVms>
                        <local:MenuItemVm Header="Item A1" />
                        <local:MenuSeparatorVm />
                        <local:MenuItemVm Header="Item A2" />
                    </local:MenuGroupVm.MenuVms>
                </local:MenuGroupVm>
                <local:MenuGroupVm Header="Group 2">
                    <local:MenuGroupVm.MenuVms>
                        <local:MenuItemVm Header="Item B1" />
                        <local:MenuItemVm Header="Item B2" />
                    </local:MenuGroupVm.MenuVms>
                </local:MenuGroupVm>
            </local:MainVm.MenuVms>
        </local:MainVm>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>

        <Menu
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            IsMainMenu="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MenuVms}"
            UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" />

        <TextBlock Text="MainContent">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuVms}"
                    UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" />
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already reported [github link here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2404)

You should use the following workarounds until the problem is fixed.

1. Set template of itemspanel for your Menu or MenuItem
2. Or you can do a similar solution within ControlTemplate of MenuItem

XAML

-1.-

```
<Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="-34,0,-54,0"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

-2.- [...within ControlTemplate...]

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" IsOpen...>
    <ItemsPresenter  Margin="-34,0,-54,0"/>
</Popup>
```